# How to hide the apps menu and odoobot in odoo 12

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

i want to hide the apps menu and the odoobot. did some research on this and found out that hiding is done by inheriting the view(xml) and customizing. I have no idea  where to find the views for these. I don't want to delete , just need to hide. Can someone please tell me where to find these views?

Comment: The Apps menu can't be seen by normal users, but usually by admins only. So why do you need to hide that? And the Odoobot is used for system notifications and alot of other things. So it will be very difficult to get rid of it.

Comment: Login as a normal user and disable the odoo bot for the user